# Create a method for return set of Predicates

Tags: java, spring-boot, predicate

I have created 3 predicates that are used inside one method of this Service class. These are the 3 Predicates that are currently in one method. But when implementing this project it seems like these predicates are useable for other service methods as well.

Therefore is there any way to get these into a separate method and call that method when we want to get these predicates? The type of Predicate also needed to change. For that can I use generics like `Predicate<T>`?

```
Predicate<LocalRequestDTO> allFilter = request -> (!StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSuvc())
        && !StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSuffix()) && !StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSite()));
Predicate<LocalRequestDTO> suvcSuffixFilter = request -> (!StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSuvc())
        && !StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSuffix()) && StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSite()));
Predicate<LocalRequestDTO> suvcFilter = request -> (!StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSuvc())
        && StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSuffix()) && StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSite()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a method that returns a `Predicate`:

```java
private static Predicate<LocalRequestDTO> allFilter() {
    return request -> (!StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSuvc()) &&
            !StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSuffix()) &&
            !StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSite()));
}
```

```java
List<LocalRequestDTO> allDto = dtos.stream()
        .filter(allFilter())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Another option is to define the `Predicate` as a constant:

```java
private static final Predicate<LocalRequestDTO> SUVC_FILTER = request ->
        (!StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSuvc()) &&
                StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSuffix()) &&
                StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSite()));
```

```java
List<LocalRequestDTO> suvcDto = dtos.stream()
        .filter(SUVC_FILTER)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or you could just create a method that accepts a DTO and returns a boolean without using predicates at all as suggested by [@Lino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5515060/lino):

```java
private static boolean doSuvcFilter(LocalRequestDTO request) {
    return !StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSuvc()) && 
            StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSuffix()) && 
            StringUtils.isBlank(request.getSite());
}
```

```java
List<LocalRequestDTO> suvcDto = dtos.stream()
        .filter(ClassNameContainingMethod::doSuvcFilter)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can't we create a single method for all the 3 predicates other than making each method for them? Because in my problem there are more than 3 predicates.

Comment: @Gayath_chandi There is nothing wrong with creating multiple methods. Somehow you need to keep the different predicates apart. Doing this in one method with an enum or switch-statement (as argument) just makes it more complex and harder to maintain IMO.